# SpringBoot,Angular method that return number

Tags: javascript, angular, spring, typescript, spring-boot

I want to get the number of users from table Users and display it on the fornt part using angular here is my methods that re returning number of the users on the Backend:

**UserRepo.Java**

```
@Query(value="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM User")
int UsersCount();
```

**UserController.Java**

```
@GetMapping("/countUsers")
  @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    public int CountUsers() {
      
     
      return  UserService.usersCount();

            
    }
```

the problem is i still cant retrieve the result as a number on the front it s always getting

*undefined*, here is how im calling my method on the ront part:

**UserService.ts**

```
 CountUsers() {  
    return this.http.get(`${AppConstants.API_URL}`+'countUsers');     }
```

**UserComp.ts**

```
 public count(){
     this.userService.CountUsers().subscribe(
     
     );
```

whenn i try to show the result this.count() returning undefined and cant also i on the service part when i try to change return type to number it s says that

> Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type 'number'

Answer (score 0):

The default `responseType` whenever you perform a `GET` request is `'json'`. That means whatever your backend is returning, the HttpClient will try to parse that as a `json`.

The result of parsing the count as JSON is probably `undefined` as you already noticed.

Try to provide the second `options` parameter and set the `responseType` to `text` instead:

```js
CountUsers(): Observable<any> {  
  return this.http.get(`${AppConstants.API_URL}`+'countUsers', { responseType: 'text' });
}
```

You can then access the result of your count by subscribing to the resulting observable:

```js
public userCount?: number;

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.userService.CountUsers().subscribe((count) => {
    this.userCount = count;
    console.log(count);
  });
}
```

Read more about it by checking out [the docs](https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-data-from-a-server).

Comment: unfortunately,im still getting the type of this.count() "undefined" and i want to add the value im getting from that method to number variable

Comment: I  think i should  convert method on the service from observable<any> to number but i dont know how

Comment: You get this error if you try to do something like `this.userCount = this.userService.CountUsers()`. If the `userCount` property is of type `number`, then you get this error. Try making your assignment inside the `subscribe` handler, instead of `console.log(count)`, assign your `userCount` property: `this.userCount = count;`.